# How do I: set up sass with Python/Flask on heroku?

Tags: heroku, flask, sass

This might be a really basic question but I'm having trouble finding how to go about it. How do I set up sass with Python (Flask) on Heroku? Can I run both python libs and ruby gems on the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just install the [sass](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sass) library for Python into your virtualenv?